# Physical push button to trigger my VB program

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port

I am making a physical push button with Arduino to trigger my VB program to select the next line, just like pressing "enter" key it should go to the next line. My problem is that I don't know how to start my code in data received part.

Comment: i would find a mcu that can act as a keyboard, then you can easily intercept "keypresses", even for keys you don't have on your physical keyboard. then you can use something like auto-it or autohotkey to do computer things when the button is pressed, without drivers or serial port complications.

Comment: Something like this would work for the Arduino:  http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you intend sending control commands from your Arduino system through the serial interface (via USB) to your VB application. If so you only need to read the serial port from your application. Here's a link to an example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/7ya7y41k.aspx
You may check your serial port in a background thread and provide any Arduino input as an event to your UI thread.
-Marcus